# Verify if a function is a palindrome in haskell

Tags: haskell

I've tried to use a function that calculate the reverse of a list. So I can use it in other function that will be the palindrome function, but always I get an error.
The first one works.

This is the code:

```
rev :: [a] -> [a]
rev [] = []
rev (x:xs) = rev xs ++ [x]

palindrome :: [a] -> Bool
palindrome [] = True
palindrome (x:xs) = if xs == rev (x:xs) then True else False
```

I have to mention that I have to do it with that signature: `[a] -> Bool`

Comment: Regarding your edit: it's not possible to write the function with that signature. Ignore that instruction and complain to the person who gave you the exercise.

Comment: Al right, I let him know.  Thanks

Comment: @DanielWagner I think @ Art Red means that `palindrome :: [a] -> Bool`. `reverse :: [a] -> Bool` is obviously impossible.

Comment: @bradrn I think the same. Do you think it is possible to write `palindrome :: [a] -> Bool`? Have you tried it?

Comment: @Daniel Wagner  I tried to re write as you said at the answer, but I got the message that says: " No instance for (Eq a) arising from a use of '=='

Comment: @DanielWagner Well, it would return `True` if the list is a palindrome, and `False` otherwise. You can write it as `(==) <*> reverse`, if you want to be unreadable.

Comment: Sorry. I remembered what did you say at the beginning. If it's not  possible with that signature what Could I do?

Comment: @ArtRed You would have to do `reverse :: [a] -> [a]`: i.e. a function which takes a list and returns the reversed list.

Comment: @bradrn I should try to do the reverse function into de palindrome function? Instance of use it as a auxiliary function?

Comment: If `xs` is a list of length N, then `x:xs` has length N+1, and `rev (x:xs)` also has length N+1. The test `xs == rev (x:xs)` compares two lists with different lengths, so it will always fail. Try fixing that. Further, note that `if a==b then True else False` is a complicated way to say `a==b`: you don't need the `if` at all.

Comment: @ArtRed You can delete the type signature and ask GHC what it thinks the type is using `:t` in ghci. Then you can put that as the type signature (or leave it with no signature).

Comment: @bradrn Seriously. Try it. You will find that `(==) <*> reverse` does *not* have the type written in this question.

Comment: Finally, I did it! Thank you guys for your help.

Comment: @DanielWagner I tried it in GHCi, and the only difference was an extra constraint: `(==) <*> reverse :: Eq a => [a] -> Bool`. Was that what you were referring to?

Comment: @bradrn Yes, that is what I was referring to.

Comment: @DanielWagner Ah, OK; I thought you were saying that it couldn’t have *any* type of the form `_ => [a] -> Bool`, which is obviously incorrect.

Answer (score 9):

Someday I will muster the energy to put together a megaquestion to address two common beginner list mistakes: thinking that `[x]` matches a list of any length, and thinking that any function on lists must have `[]` and `x:xs` patterns. This question is an example of the latter. When you do the same thing regardless of list length, you don't need multiple patterns! Just `palindrome xs = ...` is fine. Try writing your `palindrome` function again with this in mind; your bug will be fixed as a side effect.

Comment: If/when you do write that, I'd recommend using a separate Q/A for each mistake. I think we really need a reference question for the `[x]` pattern mistake, it's way too frequent (for some reason I can't understand -- is there some course/tutorial that uses `[x]` frequently?). The other mistake is less severe, IMO, since it does not lead to _wrong_ code, but only code with some redundant case. It would still be useful to a beginner to realize the redundancy and reduce the number of cases.